# Method to return a fractal sequence (1 12 123 1234 ...) as a string, but last sequence is printing twice. (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, sequence, fractals

The point of this program is to return a "fractal sequence" up until some number, n. That sounds fancy, but all it means is that if, say, n = 4, then it would return: 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4. (It just counts up to 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, and returns each step as it gets there.) To make it easier to see: 1 12 123 1234.

1. The method is called "foo", and the main method *must print* it. So, the main method calls it by going System.out.print(foo(4)).
2. The foo method must return a string.
3. Loops may appear in the foo method, but the point of the exercise is to solve the problem **recursively**, and so the bulk of the work is supposed to feature a **recursion**. Or else, this would be a lot easier with some for loops!

   ```
   public class test{
     public static void main(String args[]){

       System.out.print(foo(4));

     }
     public static String foo(int n){

       String s = "";


       if(n == 1){               //Base step of the recursion
         s = 1 + " ";
       }
       else{
         s = foo(n-1) + n + " "; //Recursive step of the recursion    
       }
       System.out.print(s);      
       return s;

     }
   }
   ```

Right now, what the program will print is 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 **1 2 3 4**.

The problem is that it is  printing out an extra set of 1 2 3 4 at the end. I realize the reason why it's doing that is because System.out.print(s) prints out everything I need, but then the extra System.out.print(foo(4)) in the main method is printing out the extra 1 2 3 4 at the end.

This could easily be solved if in the main method, I just took out System.out.print, and just wrote foo(4);. But, like rule (1) says, the main method must have the print. I'm **not** allowed to edit anything outside the foo method.

I have tried a bunch of different things (for about 7 hours or so now), but I don't seem to be "getting it". Can someone shed light on where I am going wrong?

Thank you sincerely!

Comment: If the main() needs to print, then look at getting rid of the print in the foo method and see if you can get it from there.

Comment: Please learn how to read and solve homework for yourself. You have stated by yourself that you should *not* print anything in the function and didn't event tried to remove the printing from the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
pulic class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print(foo(4));
    }

    public static String foo(int n) {
        String s = "";

        if(n == 0) {    //do nothing      
        }
        else {
            s = foo(n-1);
            System.out.print(s);
            s=s+n;
        }      
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this, and it still didn't give quite the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried  's = foo(n-1) + foo(n-1) + n + " ";' as the recursive step, as you suggested, and the output is this: 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 4. It definitely gets rid of the double print problem, but the sequence has some unwanted numbers now. Maybe my recursive step is simply wrong (since you got a lot closer).

Comment: As the OP just said, you end up with a lot of extra 1s in the output

Comment: Check the solution now, unfortunetly I don't have a compiler at the moment.

Comment: Yep, looks correct now, aside from the absence of spaces.

Comment: This is brilliant! When I was trying out different solutions, I had tried to move the print in foo around (as you moved it into the else),  and tried return s + n; etc., but just couldn't place them in the right area. I see now that I just need to really look over how my statements are arranged (and a few other things).

Also, surely I have managed the spaces :). I added + " " after the s =s+n. Thank you so much. I am trying to upvote you as much as possible. I still can't believe you were able to do it with such minor alterations!

Comment: No problem, I did tons of recursive problems like this one. But, if you have to print the results using only the `System.out` in the `main` method you should also check the answers of @DanTemple

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to:

```
public static String foo(int n){
    String s = "";


    if( n <= 0 ) {       //Base step of the recursion
        s = "";
    }
    else {
        String foo = foo(n-1);
        s = foo + foo.substring(foo(n-2).length(), foo.length() -1) + n + " "; //Recursive step of the recursion    
    }
    return s;
}
```

[Edit]:

Explanation:

What we need here is an accumulator. However, just using foo(n-1) + n will just give us the sequence 12345. So we need to get the last part of the n-1 sequence to get the full 1 12 123 1234 ... I have not tested this code, maybe you need to use foo.substring(foo.length - n, foo.length), but i thought n-1 should be correct. This just retrieves the last sequence ( 123 from 112123 ).

I changed the boundaries because i forgot the space.

With space:

```
  s = foo + foo.substring(foo.length()- n, foo.length() -1) + n + " ";
```

Without space:

```
  s = foo + foo.substring(foo.length()- (n-1), foo.length()) + n;
```

[Edit 2]

Didn't work for values n > 10, the new version uses foo(n-2) to figure out the substring. Note that this changes the complexity class for the worse. A better version would either be iterative and use dynamic programming, or use Integer Lists instead of Strings.

Comment: Is this correct!? The output I get when I try it is: `1  2 2 3  3 4`

Comment: I got the same output as with @DanTemple, unfortunately. But the substring thing seems to be a decent strategy; I'm just not sure how ti implement it, and I haven't ever used substring before. And so far, the methods we are allowed to use have been fairly elementary!

Comment: @DanTemple i forgot to account for the space, i corrected my answer

Comment: @kutschkem Have you tried this out with a value of 11 or higher? The fractal sequences after 10 seem to be missing the values at the beginning.

Comment: @DanTemple no i hav not tried this code at all. But it makes sense that it breaks down when we get to 11 and higher, because then the numbers use two characters of the String. You could solve this problem if you use a List of integers instead of a String and print the numbers in the main method instead of dealing with Strings in your function. This would be way easier than figuring out the substring you need to use.

Comment: @DanTemple i now use foo(n-2) to get the right length, this should fix it. You should consider not using Strings in that function, though, and instead loop over the list when you actually print it out.

Answer (score 1):

I first thought about an iterative solution to this.

```
//Iterative Solution
public static String bar(final int n){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
            builder.append(j);
        }
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The fact that this relies on 2 nested loops suggests to me that it is not possible to produce a recursive solution using only a single method and no loops. So I've had to include a loop to build up the individual sections within the recursion.

```
//Recursive Solution (with some iteration too)
public static String foo(final int n) {
    if( n == 1 ) {
        return 1 + " ";
    }

    String s = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s += i;
    }

    return foo(n-1) + s + " ";
}
```

Both of these produce the same output when called with 4, so my main method:

```
public static void main(final String args[]){
    System.out.println(bar(4));
    System.out.println(foo(4));
}
```

Produces this output:

> 1 12 123 1234
>
> 1 12 123 1234

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are printing the result of the recursion as well as each step. As the result is "1 2 3 4" you get this doubled.

```
1       for `System.out.print(s);` on step 1
1 2     for `System.out.print(s);` on step 2
1 2 3   for `System.out.print(s);` on step 3
1 2 3 4 for `System.out.print(s);` on step 4

1 2 3 4 for `System.out.print(foo(4));`
```

so calling `foo(4);` will get the result you want

Comment: Thanks. I happened to note this in the original, and the main problem is that I'm not allowed to get rid of the System.out.print in the main and just call foo(4) alone. I wish I could!