# How to return a fractal sequence as a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have looked around and found a few articles on this topic, but none in R. I am still relatively new to this world so bear with me.

I have been using this post as a basis but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

[Method to return a fractal sequence (1 12 123 1234 ...) as a string, but last sequence is printing twice. (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135195/method-to-return-a-fractal-sequence-1-12-123-1234-as-a-string-but-last-se)

My end goal is to create a quicker way of making a data frame for cohorts than this.

```
d1<-data.frame(days=1)
d1$days_old<-1
d2<-data.frame(days=1:2)
d2$days_old<-2
d3<-data.frame(days=1:3)
d3$days_old<-3
d4<-data.frame(days=1:4)
d4$days_old<-4
d5<-data.frame(days=1:5)
d5$days_old<-5
days<-rbind(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
```

I would like to be able to have the end day as a variable so I can expand and contract the frame based off the time frame I am running the data for, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is, but for a certain `n` (let's say 5), you could do something like `n <- 5 ; data.table::data.table(day_old = rep(1:n, 1:n))[,  days := 1:.N, by = day_old][]`

Comment: See, also, `sequence(seq_len(n))`

Comment: @alexis_laz forgot about `sequence`... Seems like `cbind(sequence(seq_len(n)), rep(1:n, 1:n))` will be it then.

Comment: Thank yall both for the insight, I used cbind(sequence(seq_len(n)), rep(1:n, 1:n)) and it worked like a charm. It ended up taking out a ton of extra lines.